# catch a specific exception before collecting data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Android with jetpack compose APP that is using API in order to login...

Somewhere in the AuthViewModel I have this API call:

```
authRepository.login(auth)
    .catch { e -> // here catch a specific Exception ex: UnknownHostException} 
    .collect { result -> ... }
```

I can see the message from the exception that is thrown with Log:

```
 .catch { e -> Log.d("DEBUG_API", e.toString()) }
```

But i want  to display a custom message to the client (not the original message:  `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.example.com": No address associated with hostname`

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I think I got it:

```
.catch { error ->
    when (error) {
        is UnknownHostException -> Log.d("DEBUG_API", "unkwnon host exception message")
        else -> Log.d("DEBUG_API", "other excetion message")
   }
}
```

... and seems to work... is that simple ? :)

Comment: Inside catch, you can still emit the data. So there you can use a response model with custom error message.

Comment: Do you still have a question or should this be closed? Did you want to just log the error, or pass something that can be shown in the UI?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it can be closed....I am updating the uiState with the error message, instead of the Log :-)